# SharePoint Search 2013 crawls stuck - never commit

Tags: search, sharepoint-2013

SharePoint 2013 search crawls getting stuck for one content source with index count around 300K. When I kick off crawls the success count grows pretty steadily and performance is not an issue. The small content source with 5-7K index would finish fine. This is started recently. The problem I suspect is, search process never commits the transaction. Here is the ULS error.

mssearch.exe (0x0FA8)                       0x39D0  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Gatherer Plugin         ac6s7   High        **ManagedSqlSession caught a SqlException executing the following command: 'proc_MSS_CommitTransactions'.** Connection string was: 'Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=SSA_CrawlStoreDB;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[OWSTIMER][1][SSA_CrawlStoreDB]'  Original exception message: **'Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 32768.  Duplicate key was ignored.'**  Stack trace '   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParser...

```
Detailed error posted on my blog
```

http://nitrohn.blogspot.com/2016/10/sharepoint-2013-search-crawl.html

Any ideas how to fix?